# Как обратится к объекту через индекс как в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект. Как обратится через индекс как в массиве?
Могу и понимаю как делать. В коде реализовал. Хочу и другой вариант.

```js
var person = {
  firstName: {
    some: 'sdfsdfsdf15'
  },
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

console.log(person.lastName);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="the enter">
<button>Send</button>
```

Comment: Интересно кто это минусует вопросы и ответы? и хочет закрыть потому что он не понял вопрос? В место того что бы нормальный вопрос минусовать спросите если не поняли суть.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам необходимо перебрать все поля объекта то можно сделать так

```js
var obj = {
  p1: "hi",
  p2: "hi, there",
  p3: "hallow, all!"
};

for (var key in obj) {
  var value = obj[key];
  console.log(`key: ${ key }, value: ${ value }`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В `javascript` есть метод `keys`, при помощи которого достаем индексы объекта.

```js
obj = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"};
    var idx0 = 0; // key1
    var idx1 = 1; // key2

    var key0 = Object.keys(obj)[idx0];
    var key1 = Object.keys(obj)[idx1];
    var value0 = obj[key0];
    var value1 = obj[key1];

    console.log(key0,value0);
    console.log(key1,value1);
```